# Error : not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

```
public Boolean DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(/*snip*/)
{            
    if (/*snip*/)
    {   
        if (/*snip*/) { return true; }
        else if (/*snip*/) { return true; }
        else if ((/*snip*/) { return true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. Missing question... and explanation of what is unclear in the error message.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov FYI: The explanation's in the title.

Comment: @JohnLBevan That's not an explanation, it's just stating what the error message is.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah ok - I see what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

You failed to return a value in the else case:

```
public Boolean DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(/*snip*/)
{            
    if (/*snip*/)
    {   
        if (/*snip*/) { return true; }
        else if (/*snip*/) { return true; }
        else if ((/*snip*/) { return true; }
        else{return false;}
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution won't work if it passes the outer 'if' evaluation and subsequently fails the inner conditions.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. Editing...

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend doing the following:

```
public Boolean DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(/*snip*/)
{
    bool result = false;            
    if (/*snip*/)
    {   
        if (/*snip*/) { result = true; }
        else if (/*snip*/) { result = true; }
        else if (/*snip*/) { result =true; }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Having a single return statement makes it simpler to follow what's going on, and ensuring it's outside of any conditional statements and is initialised when declared ensures you'll always return a value.

Comment: this question actually stems from another question and that is exactly what I said to do. Cheers.

Comment: I'd recommend *against* doing that. If the result of checking one condition obviates the need to check the others, and your method has nothing else to do, return from the method! I don't agree with the "single point of return" viewpoint.

Comment: @DanielMann agreed that sometimes multiple return statements can be better.  For me in the above circumstance you're not adding any overhead on the original code, but it is neater than adding the additional else statements. Putting a single return false on the end is as straight forward as the above, but for me (pure personal preference) the above is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The following:

```
if (A)
{   
    if (B) { return true; }
    else if (C) { return true; }
    else if (D) { return true; }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
return A && (B || C || D);
```

(Assuming that any case previously not returning any value implied returning false.)

Comment: That is a cool solution.

Answer (score 2):

Without an `else` as a catch-all for the remaining conditions, you need to add a `return false;` following your logic checks.

```
public Boolean DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(/*snip*/)
{            
    if (/*snip*/)
    {   
        if (/*snip*/) { return true; }
        else if (/*snip*/) { return true; }
        else if (/*snip*/) { return true; }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: DAFUQ im sorry maybe because i was high hours ago it affected it to my mind :D rly Weed = Stupidity

Answer (score 2):

You are not always returning a value:

```
    if (playerPositionM.Y <= groundPositionM.Y + groundM.Height && playerPositionM.Y > groundPositionM.Y)
    {   
        if (playerPositionM.X < groundPositionM.X && (playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width > groundPositionM.X)) 
        { 
            return true; 
        }
        else if (playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width > groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && (playerPositionM.X < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && playerPositionM.X > groundPositionM.X))
        { 
            return true; 
        }
        else if ((playerPositionM.X > groundPositionM.X && playerPositionM.X < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width) && (playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width > groundPositionM.X)) 
        { 
            return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            // You need to return a value here:
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // You need to return a value here:
    }

etc!
```